# Getting TypeError("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s" % (obj, type(obj)))

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm creating a spark session (spark version 2.2.1) like below

```
SparkS = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("Test")\
    .master("local[*]")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

then creating sparkcontext like below

```
raw_data = SparkS\
    .sparkContext\
    .textFile("C:\\Users\\...\\RawData\\nasdaq.csv")
```

for verification purposes I'm printing the data using:

```
print(raw_data.take(3))
```

and output is

`['43084,6871.549805,6945.819824,6871.450195,6936.580078,6936.580078,3510420000', '43087,6980.399902,7003.890137,6975.540039,6994.759766,6994.759766,2144360000', '43088,6991.25,6995.879883,6951.490234,6963.850098,6963.850098,2071060000']`

Now I'm converting the RDD into a datafrme by defining schema like below:

```
schema = StructType().add("date", StringType())\
                     .add("open", StringType())\
                     .add("high", StringType())\
                     .add("low", StringType())\
                     .add("close", StringType())\
                     .add("adj_close", StringType())\
                     .add("volume", StringType())

geioIP = SparkS.createDataFrame(raw_data,schema)
print(geioIP)
```

The output is:

```
DataFrame[date: string, open: string, high: string, low: string, close: string, adj_close: string, volume: string]
```

So far so good but problem is when i call `geioIP.show(2)`, it gives me a error

```
18/01/23 12:58:48 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 177, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 172, in process
  File "C:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "C:\Users\rajnish.kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 520, in prepare
    verify_func(obj, schema)
  File "C:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1371, in _verify_type
    raise TypeError("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s" % (obj, type(obj)))
TypeError: StructType can not accept object '43084,6871.549805,6945.819824,6871.450195,6936.580078,6936.580078,3510420000' in type <class 'str'>
```

After going through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986179/python-the-hard-way-exercise-6-r-versus-s), what I did was convert all the csv data into text format but I'm still getting above issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each row in the RDD is a single string (i.e. one column) and your schema contains 7 columns. The RDD is not actually converted into a dataframe until you use an action (like `show`) which is why it does not crash immediately.

Since you want to have the data in a dataframe, the easiest solution would be to read the data as a dataframe in the beginning:

```
geioIP = SparkS.read.csv("C:\\Users\\...\\RawData\\nasdaq.csv", schema=schema)
```

---

Or if you want to continue to use RDD and `createDataFrame`, you could use the `split` function (possibly with `strip` if you have spaces).

```
raw_data = raw_data.map(lambda x: [c.strip() for c in x.split(',')])
geioIP = SparkS.createDataFrame(raw_data,schema)
```

Comment: @ Shaido thanks for the reminding me that " each row in the RDD is a single string (i.e. one column) and your schema contains 7 columns.  " , it helped me to think in a proper way but i was looking to solve above scenario not by reading the data as a dataframe in the begning

Comment: @rajNishKuMar: No problem. Added information to make the answer more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Hi thankyou to @ Shaido for pointing out the most basic thing regarding RDD that  "each row in the RDD is a single string (i.e. one column) and your schema contains 7 columns."
and talking help form this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676594/spark-sql-typeerrorstructtype-can-not-accept-object-in-type-s-typeobj) i was able to solve above issue

before using **raw_data** directly in

```
geioIP = SparkS.createDataFrame(raw_data,schema)
```

i need to create a list of RDD which i did like this

```
rawdata = raw_data.map(lambda x : x.split(","))
```

now calling

```
geioIP = SparkS.createDataFrame(rawdata,schema)
geioIP.show(2)
```

yields

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| date|       open|       high|        low|      close|  adj_close|    volume|
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|43084|6871.549805|6945.819824|6871.450195|6936.580078|6936.580078|3510420000|
|43087|6980.399902|7003.890137|6975.540039|6994.759766|6994.759766|2144360000|
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

convert your raw data to this:
[Row(x) for x in raw_data]

Comment: Can you explain your implementation in more detail?